# Connect tableau to bitnami django stack postgres database

Tags: postgresql, google-compute-engine, tableau-api, bitnami

I am trying to connect the tableau to bitnami django stack which is being hosted on GCP instance with postgres database(included in bitnami django stack).

Am trying to connect the tableau to my postgres for better analytics.

I have already tried connecting to the local development system and that works fine for me, but when I try the server it is giving me the following error

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) 
Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port xxxx?
```

Would like to open mydatabase for the specific connection.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

By default, the database port for the nodes in this solution cannot be accessed over a public IP address. As a result, you will only be able to connect to your database nodes from machines that are running in the same network. For security reasons, we do not recommend making the database port accessible over a public IP address. If you must make it accessible over a public IP address, we recommend restricting access to a trusted list of source IP addresses using firewall rules.

You will need to go to the Google Dashboard, create a new firewall and assign that firewall to the Google's instance.

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/components/postgresql/#how-to-connect-to-postgresql-from-a-different-machine

I hope this helps,
Jota